# Finding the color of a detected blob opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

currently i have beans that detected by a simpleblobdetector function. Now I want to know the RGB/HSV value of the beans detected by the blob detector, what is the best way to find the color? Someone suggest me to use Histogram Calculation but I still don't know how to apply this function.

```
            Mat im_with_keypoints;
                   drawKeypoints( capture, keypoints, im_with_keypoints, Scalar(0,0,255), DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS );
                   size_t i, k;
                   Point Coordinate;
                    for( i = k = 0; i < keypoints.size(); i++ )
                    {
                        Coordinate =    keypoints[i].pt ;
                    qDebug ()<< "x " << Coordinate.x << "y " <<Coordinate.y;
                    qDebug ()<< "s " << keypoints[i].size ;

                    }
```

This is my Code to detect the Coordinate and the diameter of each blob

Comment: https://docs.opencv.org/4.5.1/d8/dbc/tutorial_histogram_calculation.html

Answer (score 0):

If you know the box which can contain the individual bean; you could take mean avarage of all the pixels' in that box. It wouldn't be perfect since it will include background's color too but if you use certain colors for beans (i.e easily differentiable colors); you could compute the distance between all the possible colors of beans and the currently calculated one.

Using histograms would be another option too.

Comment: is it possible that i make a mask from the circle of the blob detector, and then calculate the mean average inside the mask?

Comment: Well, it would work fine most of the time for circular objects. I'd do a mask which is smaller than the "bean box" so that it is guaranteed to pick up only the bean's color.